# How to send ID with axios.delete() request

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm making Todo List project (Pure js) and I'm trying to bind backend (node.js/express.js) with frontend. I'm stuck on the axios.delete(). All i want it to do is:When button "delete" is clicked, delete that item from the page and from the database, but I don't know how to pass the id of that item.

I am new to JavaScript.

```
const deleteData = () => {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/delete/:id', {

    })
}
```

Comment: `axios.delete(\`http://localhost:3000/delete/${id}\`)` replacing *id* with a variable containing an ID. To set a variable, I'd add an id to the button referencing the item, then when it's clicked just retrieve the value from the tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry to bother u even more,but can you give an example please?

Comment: What are you using on the front end? Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Yes I'm using vanilla js

Answer (score -1):

```
const deleteData = (id) => {
    axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/delete/${id}', {
    })
}
```

> Did you tried this?
> look for Template strings:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).